# Possessive case in 'Jacobi identity'

Tags: possessives, mathematics

I am not sure this is the right place to ask, but I give it a try anyway.

I am reading a book about how to write math. At some point the author shows the grammar rule for the possessive case: e.g. one usually writes 'Stokes's theorem', 'Bliss's book', 'van der Corput's lemma', and so on. He does not mention the so called '[Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity)'. According to the general rule, I would write 'Jacobi's identity'. Is there a specific reason why we do not do it?

Comment: When **Jacobi** is part of the *name* of this identity (note the article in *the Jacobi identity*) it is adjectival in nature and doesn't refer to Jacobi the person any longer, at least not directly.  It is not the same as "Fermat's Last Theorem" where **Fermat** refers directly to the mathematician.

Comment: So suppose I am writing a paper and at some point I use that identity. Using the expression '(...) so by Jacobi identity (...)' should be wrong. Is that correct?

Comment: Once the name becomes widely used, it is difficult to say how people who use the name would understand the possessive there. And there is no clear demarcation when the name becomes a name and the possessive falls out of use; sometimes both forms exist side-by-side, as in *the Heisenberg principle* and *Heisenberg's principle*.

Comment: I could ask you *Have you read the new Bliss book?* and mean "the new book by Bliss"  (assuming Bliss to be a living person--I'm not a mathematician) or "the new book about Bliss".  Nouns used as adjectives are often ambiguous because their precise functional role is not fully apparent.

Comment: In my understanding, 'Have you read the new Bliss book?' is different from 'Have you read the new Bliss's book?'. The first one means 'about Bliss', the second 'by Bliss'. I am not a native English speaker, so I am likely wrong, please correct me.

Comment: **the new Bliss's book** is ungrammatical, unless there are two Blisses, one of them a relative newcomer on the scene.  As I wrote, **the new Bliss book** could be "by Bliss" or "about Bliss".

Comment: Then there must be a mistake in the book I am reading, because I read 'Bliss's book' is a perfectly fine expression.

Comment: I wrote ***the** new Bliss's book*. Note the article. The combination of the article **the** with the possessive name **Bliss's** is ungrammatical.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comments, I need to think a bit about this.

Comment: A possessive name is a specifier and you won't find **a** or **the** when there is already a specifier, in standard English.   *Joe's hat* not  *the Joe's hat*.

Comment: You should *not* write **the Joe hat**, not unless **Joe** is the name of a brand or something like that. If Joe is a person, it's *Joe's hat*.

Comment: I erased my last comment, I was too quick. Suppose that Joe's hat is very famous because has a huge hole on top and is very colourful. Would you not say 'the Joe's hat' meaning exactly that specific hat?

Comment: No, you would not combine **the** and **Joe's**.  **the Joe's hat** is not grammatical.  You'd say something like "The hat Joe wears" or simply "Joe's hat".  When there is a possessive proper name like **Joe's**, do not use the article.

Comment: Nobody ever refers to [***Hawking's radiation***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) either. It's not obvious to me there's any useful / learnable rule in play here. The name of a thing is whatever it's called - grammar and syntax hardly get a lookl-in.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is to use the possessive as in "Euler's identity" but particular usage may overrule this in many situations.  In particular, when using "the" we tend to use the name attributively without forming the possessive:

> Euler's identity was in fact first proved by Bernoulli.
>
> The Euler identity relates five fundamental constants.

In the case of Jacobi, it seems many of the things named after him use his name attributively: "The Jacobi symbol", "The Jacobi identity". However, we still speak of "Jacobi's formula".

So no simple rule can be derived for why and you just can follow established use.